# Not able to validate a date with the json schema

Tags: json, json.net, jsonschema

I want my date format to be MM-dd-yyyy, and as you said format=date takes yyyy-MM-dd.
so can i create my own custom format=customdate? if yes, then how can it be acheived?
here's my requirements and my problems
Requirement
Store date in MM-dd-yyyy format into my JSON object as type string after validating my JSON object with the JSON schema
Problem
Getting ErrorType=Format validation error when I try to validate MM-dd-yyyy date with the JSON schema

The Validation Error which I am getting is String '09-09-1966' does not validate against format 'date'.

MY JSON SCHEMA LOOKS LIKE THIS

```
"title": myjsonschema,
"type": "object",
"properties": {
  "birthDate": {
    "type": [
             "string",
             "null"
            ],
    "format": "date",
    "pattern": "^(0?[1-9]|1[012])\\-(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\\-\\d{4}$",
    "message": {
             "pattern": "This field should be in mm-dd-yyyy format"
    }
  }
}
```

MY JSON OBJECT

```
{"birthday":"09-09-1966"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to look at the implementation you are using.

`format` is an annotation only, meaning by default it does nothing in terms of validation.

Anything it does do in terms of validation is implementation specific.

If it DOES do something, JSON Schema spec does specify what that should be. "date" is the "full-date" production from RFC3339, which is `date-fullyear "-" date-month "-" date-mday`. Your date doesn't start with the year.

Comment: If `format` does nothing in terms of validation then why am I getting `ErrorType=Format` in Validation Error.

My end goal is to update the JSON with date string, validate it with the schema and then store it into the database. So, when I validate my JSON object with the schema I am getting this error. Any Solution?

Comment: Edited to reflect further problems.

Comment: I have edited the question, I want the date format in MM-dd-yyyy format. 
should i have to create my own `format` ? if yes, then how it can be achieved?

Comment: You'll have to look at the documentation for the implementation you are using.

Comment: okay thanks my issue has been resolved, I have removed `"format"="date"` and Added the pattern of MM-dd-YYYY date into my json schema